# How does the name lookup in a Names field work?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a problem with name lookups when creating a new email to a person where there are two people with the same name.

The first thing to mention is that we have our company contacts database listed as a local address book as well as the Domino Directory.

If there are two people with the same first name and surname in our contacts database, e.g. Phil Jones of company1 (phil.jones@fakecompany1.com) and Phil Jones of company2 (phil.jones@fakecompany2.com) the problem arises as follows.

Create a new mail and type "Jones" into the To field, and click on the *Search directory for "Jones"* drop-down option, only the second one is listed.  When you select it, the first one is added to the To field.  This can be checked by right-clicking on the name and selecting *Show Name Details*, of by pressing *F9* to expand the name.

My educated guess is that over the years (and releases) since our contacts database was created, the mail and domino directory templates have changed, and that the *($Users)* view that we use needs to be updated.

Can anyone confirm that it is the *($Users)* view that is used by the EnterSendTo field in the *Message|Memo* form in the Mail85.ntf template?  As far as I can tell it is a normal Names field with *None* selected in the choices option.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [Script Debugger](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ENABLING_THE_LOTUSSCRIPT_DEBUGGER_STEPS.html) to see what's going on, and using Domino Designer to look into the `Mail85.ntf` template to find out what the code is doing, and which view is used.

You seem to have `Recipient Name Lookup` set up (not `Type-ahead`), with `Stop after first match`.

See [Technote 1105261 - Differences between Recipient Name Lookup and Recipient Name Type-ahead](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21105261) for details.

See also [Directory search order for a name in a Notes address field](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/plan_directorysearchorderforanameinanotesaddressfiel_t.dita). and [IBM Lotus Notes 8 Recent Contacts and Type-ahead features: FAQs](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/ibm-lotus-notes-8-recent-contacts-and-type-ahead-features-faqs) if you decided to use Type-ahead and Recent Contacts.

What version of Notes/Domino with what version of the templates are you running?

Make sure you are running a supported configuration: [Supported configurations for Notes/Domino 8.0.x and 8.5.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358406)